# Installing Pre-Requisites of SharePoint 2013 but

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am installing pre-requisistes for SP 2013 but Windows App Fabric is stuck while installing and I cant even install it manually, it says the operating system is not supported. I am using Windows 2008 server Web Server edition.

Let me know what to do

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 does not support Windows Server 2008, only Windows Server 2008 R2:

> The 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1) Standard, Enterprise, or Datacenter or the 64-bit edition of Windows Server 2012 Standard or Datacenter

Web Server edition is not supported as well...

You might want to review the software requirements:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section4